# Regarding Time Series analysis in earth engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine

I have been working on time series change using Landsat 5,7 and 8 satellite images. The objective of my study is to see any changes in features like forest, agriculture etc over time using NDVI
To observe and visualize the changes, firstly I need a  combine chart of monthly NDVI of all above landsat series.

Secondly, I have made mean images of ndvi for each year (a mean of all of the months). I wish to make a chart of mean annual ndvi values vs years, for all the features.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: i want combine chart  of  monthly NDVI  in earth engine

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is pretty broad, but there are sufficient examples inside the Google Earth Engine to get you started. If you will have a specific question later on you can ask it with the piece of code you have been trying so far.

See this example to calculate normalized differences (for example NDVI and NDWI):

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e062e11bb632c20ce320c5f7f10dc41

Then follow this example script by Google to make a time-series analysis:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7bfc69498939433590a040e11fd949b1

You can find manny other examples under script -> Examples in the code editor.

Comment: I want extract annual  Landsat  NDVI  images of each year  Using  Earth engine how  can i extract it

Answer (score 0):

```
// for graph/chart that contain mean NDVI of every year

     var plotNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(addnullimages, studyarea,ee.Reducer.mean(),
'nd',500,'system:index')
              .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
                title: 'NDVI short-term time series',
                hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'}
});


  print(plotNDVI);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code....

```
// for graph/chart that contain mean NDVI of every year

  var plotNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(addnullimages, studyarea,ee.Reducer.mean(),
'nd',500,'system:index')
              .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
                title: 'NDVI short-term time series',
                hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'}
});


  print(plotNDVI);
```

Comment: Is this answer any different from your answer above? Probably worth deleting one and expanding on (fleshing out an explanation for) the other.